# r barplot descending order with matrix data with one column

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, bar-chart

I have a matrix data:

```
data <- prop.table(df,2)*100

   [,1]
FR 63.60582
US 15.90146
DE 10.07839
UK 10.41433
```

I do a barplot of it:

```
barplot(data ,beside=TRUE,legend.text=T,
        ylim=c(0,100),ylab="Percentages",
        args.legend = list(x ='topright', bty='n', inset=c(-0.5,0)))
```

it is not ordered **descending**, so I try to order it like:

```
data <- data [order(data $V1),]
```

and I get:

```
Error in data$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

so I try to convert to dataframe:

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

and then do a barplot with it, but I get:

```
Error in barplot.default(data, beside = TRUE, legend.text = T, ylim = c(0,  : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

I have the impression that I am stuck in a vicious circle here. Could somebody get me out of this chaos? thanks.

### update:

dput(data) gives me:

```
structure(c(63.6058230683091, 15.9014557670773, 10.0783874580067, 
10.4143337066069), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("FR", 
"US", "DE", "UK"), NULL))
```

Comment: Try replacing `data` with `data[,1]`?

Comment: @MikeH. in which line do you mean?

Comment: After you convert to a `data.frame`, in your barplot call try: `barplot(data[,1] ,beside=TRUE,legend.text=T,
        ylim=c(0,100),ylab="Percentages",
        args.legend = list(x ='topright', bty='n', inset=c(-0.5,0)))`

Comment: @MikeH. when i do so, i lose my legend and the default colors for the bars... why is it so ugly?

Comment: Hmm can you do a `dput(data)` and post it?

Comment: Also the reason you get the error: `Error in data$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` is because you can't use `$` on a matrix, if you want to order the matrix you could do: `data [order(data[,"V1"]),]`

Comment: @MikeH. i posted what you asked for. could you please suggest a working answer for this? so that i can keep my default colors for the bars and the legend... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `Error in data$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` is because you can't use the `$` operator for matrices. If you wanted to order by a specific column, you could do: `data[order(data[,1]),]` - this would order by the first column. It also works with character vectors too.

To answer your question with the data you posted this should work:

```
barplot(data[order(data[,1]),] ,beside=TRUE,legend.text=T,
        ylim=c(0,100),ylab="Percentages",
        args.legend = list(x ='topright', bty='n', inset=c(-0.5,0)))
```

[image]